# Mathematica Plot3D does not produce a plot when graphing a user-defined function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, finance

I'm writing a simple Mathematica implementation of the black-scholes model and using Plot3D to plot the pricing surface. However, when I run this code, no plot is produced. My `call` and `put` functions to produce correct values when run separately, but no plot is produced. Code:

```
Clear[d1, d2, call, put, stockPrice, strikePrice, riskFreeRate, timeToExp, volatility]

d1[stockPrice_, strikePrice_, riskFreeRate_, timeToExp_, volatility_] := (Log[stockPrice / strikePrice] + (riskFreeRate + 0.5*volatility^2)*timeToExp) / (volatility * Sqrt[timeToExp])

d2[stockPrice_, strikePrice_, riskFreeRate_, timeToExp_, volatility_] := d1[stockPrice, strikePrice, riskFreeRate, timeToExp, volatility] - volatility*Sqrt[timeToExp]

call[stockPrice_, strikePrice_, riskFreeRate_, timeToExp_, 
  volatility_] := stockPrice * CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], d1[stockPrice, strikePrice, riskFreeRate, timeToExp, volatility]] - strikePrice * Exp[-riskFreeRate*timeToExp] *CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], d2[stockPrice, strikePrice, riskFreeRate, timeToExp, volatility]]

Plot3D[call[stockPrice, 500, 0.0030, timeToExp, 0.39], {stockPrice, 
  10, 1000}, {timeToExp, 0.0833333, 5}]
```

Other plots, like this sample from the reference, do work.

```
Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

Comment: I was informed that Stack Exchange has a [Mathematica site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). Would this question get more help there, or should it remain here?

Comment: You have made a misprint: `timeToExp` vs `timetoExp`. Replace one with another in the last input line and you will get the desired plot. Note that syntax highlighting is you friend in such cases!

Comment: Questions here are still answered, but please consider using the Mathematica site for future questions.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll post my related questions there in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have `timeToExp` `call[]` and `timetoExp` (lowercase t) in the specification of the plot range.

Comment: Unbelievable. camel case curses me yet again. Thanks for catching that.